# Restart application on preference changed

Tags: android

I need to restart the application from `PreferenceActivity` on preference changed. I tried:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences pref, String key) {
    System.exit(2);
}
```

but after restart settings are not saved. Any ideas of how to restart the app with preferences are saved?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to restart the app?

Comment: There are only 2 settings - change theme and change locale. I've not found any solution of how to change them without restart.

Comment: Then I suggest that you open new StackOverflow questions asking about how to "change theme" and "change locale" (whatever you think those are) without restarting the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a System.exit(2); I would try a

```
  this.finish();
```

finish() is the call to stop the activity.

to start an activity you need an intent object

```
 Intent screenToBeShown = new Intent(myactivity.this, whateveractivityyouwant.class); 
 startActivity(screenToBeShown);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it works. I was sure that all the code after `finish()` is unreachable.

Comment: Oh... :( I have to close also all the parent activities. Do you know how to close **all** previous activities?

Comment: That works for an activity, but what about a service?

Answer (score 1):

If it's still useful for you: restart an app with AlarmManager:

```
AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, myActivity.class), 0));
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```